# How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?

Tags: html, mobile, camera

In my web app (not native app) for mobiles, I want to take a photo and upload it, but I don't want to use Adobe Flash. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "Webpage" means, it should be easily able to accessed from any kind of clients/devices. So, should i set restrictions?

Comment: I assume, you want to access the hardware camera, right?

Comment: Hmm.. "Camera" of the Mobile Smart Phones / etc.. from the webpage.

Comment: Hi, this is a subject I'm currently studying for my own projects. PWAs enable you to use native device features in modern browsers: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Safari & Chrome on iOS 6+ and Android 2.2+ support HTML Media Capture which allows you to take pictures with your device's camera or select an existing one:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*">`

Here's how it works on iOS 10:

[image]

Android 3.0+ and Safari on iOS10.3+ also support the `capture` attribute which is used to jump straight to the camera.

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`

`capture="camera"` (String) and `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` (Parameter) were part of old specs and were replaced by `capture` (Boolean) the W3C Candidate Recommendation.

Support documentation: this [2013 O'Reilly book](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=gswdarRZVUoC&pg=PA263&dq=%22file+upload+compatibility+table%22) and [my testing](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/)

Comment: Mine on Android just jumps straight to Selecting photos, but not giving me the option for Camera even when i have set capture="camera"....totally stuck

Comment: @Benyaman Try with `capture` instead of `capture="camera"` .  Curious what device & Android version.

Comment: I did, on Android 5.0 apparently Phonegap doesnt have HTML capture built in. So it can't capture things, no camrecord, no audio, no Camera. I had to build a work around.

Comment: Thanks for uploading the photos for illustration, it's helpful.

Comment: you can also do capture="environment" nowadays

Answer (score 297):

In iPhone iOS6 and from Android ICS onwards, HTML5 has the following tag which allows you to take pictures from your device:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

`Capture` can take values like camera, camcorder and audio.

I think this tag will definitely not work in iOS5, not sure about it.

Comment: Here's great tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: GetUserMedia is not required here.

Comment: I get a "getUserMedia() not supported by this device" - but I am on safari and have ios7 - why? – Dan just now edit

Comment: I think maybe the code should be `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">` instead. [According to MDN, there's no `capture` attribute for an `input` element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: Worked perfectly on iOS and Android for me. Found a test page at http://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23 for anyone not wanting to write up their own test.

Comment: After capturing an image it shows what appears to be a filename consisting of a long string of digits and ending in "jpg".  Where is this (presumably) temporary file stored at?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables   can you do this for multiple files like : **<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" capture="camera">**

Comment: Both `capture="camera"` (String) and the older `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` have been replaced in 2012 with `capture="capture"` (Boolean) . The attribute is used to force capture instead of selecting from the library. See [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/) and [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/)

Comment: Works on IOS as well. If you remove capture="camera", you get the option to use camera / upload from gallery

Comment: in Adnroid, this solution gives me options for camera along with library as well. I just want to open straight camera in android. how do I do this?

Answer (score 68):

Just to update this, the standard now is:

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

to access the environment-facing (rear) camera, and

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user">
```

for user-facing (front) camera. To access video, substitute "video" for "image" in name.

Tested on iPhone 5c, running iOS 10.3.3, firmware 760, works fine.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/

Comment: Is there a way to take a photo with my notebook's camera on a desktop browser? This solutions appearently only works on mobile devices. However the spec's page suggest that it could work on desktop too: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/images/file-upload-state.png

Answer (score 42):

Nowadays at least with android it's relatively easy. Just use normal file input tag and when user clicks it the phone will ask if user wants to use camera (or file managers etc..) to upload a file. Just take a photo with the camera and it will automatically be added and uploaded.

No idea about iphone. Maybe someone can enlighten on that.
EDIT: Iphone works similarly.

Sample of the input tag:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: can you do this for multiple files like : **multiple="multiple"**

Comment: example: **<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" capture="camera">**

Comment: `multiple` works both on Android and iOS, see [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/)

Comment: Not sure for other apple device, at least this solution also works on iPad now.

Answer (score 5):

well, there's a new HTML5 features for accessing the native device camera - "getUserMedia API"

NOTE: HTML5 can handle photo capture from a web page on Android devices (at least on the latest versions, run by the Honeycomb OS; but it can’t handle it on iPhones but  iOS 6 ).

Comment: oh sorry is call setUserMedia API

Answer (score 4):

AppMobi HTML5 SDK once promised access to native device functionality - including the camera - from an HTML5-based app, but is no longer Google-owned. Instead, try the [HTML5-based answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431475/html5-camera-access).

Comment: I don't believe Google has any ownership over AppMobi or their products.

Comment: Ah - my mistake, because it's on the Chrome web store - Google reference removed. Here are the real partners: http://www.appmobi.com/?page_id=468

Answer (score 4):

You can use WEBRTC but unfortunately it is not supported by all web browsers. BELOW IS THE LINK TO SHOW WHICH BROWSERS supports it
http://caniuse.com/stream

And this link gives you an idea of how you can access it(sample code).
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: WebRTC and `getUserMedia` is overkill, `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to access the camera.

This tutorial outlines the basics of accessing a device camera from the browser: https://medium.com/@aBenjamin765/make-a-camera-web-app-tutorial-part-1-ec284af8dddf

Note: This works on most Android devices, and in iOS in Safari only.

Comment: On IOS it depends on your IOS-Version, if you can use getUserMedia for Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: To be honest, 99% of people should not use `getUserMedia` as its really intended for low level integration with the camera and other media devices. `getUserMedia` should only be used when you want to build your own camera app top to bottom. If you just want the user to take photos and share them with the web app the `<input type="file"...` is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that security features have been implemented which require either the app to be ran locally under localhost, or through SSL for GetUserMedia() to work.

I discovered this when trying several of the demos available and was dissapointed when they didn't work! See: [New Security Restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34216154/1819403)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to access a mobile phone's camera from the web browser without some additional mechanism (i.e. Flash or some type of container that allows access to the hardware API)

For the latter have a look at PhoneGap: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

With this you should be able to access the camera at least on iOS and Android-based devices.

Comment: That still requires that an app be installed on the mobile device, which is what I think the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta do you know a better way?

Comment: I don't believe what the OP is asking for is possible.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta that's what I think as well. And the best way I can think of would be PhoneGap, since it works on iOS (which Flash doesn't). Still it's native, true, but allows at least a bit of cross-platform access to cameras from a web page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can - there is a [W3C draft API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) to get audio or video, but there is no implementation yet on any of the major mobile OSs.

<strike>Second best</strike> The only option is to go with Dennis' suggestion to use PhoneGap. This will mean you need to create a native app and add it to the mobile app store/marketplace.

Comment: sorry to repost - i was looking to see if you got around the NPE exception with jersey client on android. stuck :(