# HTML5: camera access

Tags: html, camera, native

I am quite new to `HTML5`. I try the following `HTML5` code to access camera on my mobile phone. It always display *"Native web camera not supported"*. It seems that my mobile browser (safari and android 2.1 web browser) does not support the camera.

Could you please tell me which browser should I use to access to camera?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {width: 100%;}
        canvas {display: none;}
    </style>
    <script>
        var video, canvas, msg;
        var load = function () {
            video  = document.getElementById('video');
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            msg    = document.getElementById('error');
            if( navigator.getUserMedia ) {
                video.onclick = function () {
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 240, 320);
                    var image = {"demo" : {
                        "type"  : "device",
                        "image" : canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                    }};
                };

                var success = function ( stream ) {
                    video.src = stream;
                };

                var error = function ( err ) {
                    msg.innerHTML = "Error: " + err.code;
                };

                navigator.getUserMedia('video', success, error);

            } else {
                msg.innerHTML = "Native web camera not supported :(";
            }

        };

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video  id="video" width="240" height="320" autoplay> </video>
    <p      id="error">Click on the video to send a snapshot to the receiving screen</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="320"> </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML5's WebCam API is still very new, and it's not even very widely supported on *desktops*, much less mobile devices. You can't depend on it being available.

Comment: see here for a demo of HTML5 Microphone & Camera access in Chrome.. this is bleeding edge stuff.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=VP0SV3YWOWA#t=1425s

Comment: HTML5 mobile support no longer "bleeding edge" - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13489553/957950 for how to get images directly from the camera, or test example at http://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23. Welcome to the future! Still no hoverboards, sorry. :(

Answer (score 40):

The `getUserMedia` method is now supported on Firefox 17+,Chrome 23+ and Opera 12+. (See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia))

[image: Screenshot of the CanIUse.com support grid as of 2/24/12]

Comment: I have installed chrome on my ipad but still does not open the video

Comment: @Anthony, Question was asked about accessing camera on Mobile phone. Firefox 17+, Chrome 23+, Opera 12+ are not available on Mobile!

Answer (score 14):

This works on Firefox mobile, Chrome mobile, iPhone and Android:

```
<input type="file" id="mypic" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Does this invoke the camera on iPhones and Android phones?

Comment: That's not WebRTC or related to getuserMedia(). It was related to the proposed HTML Media Capture which will probably go away. More info [here](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/).

Comment: @Travis M: It launches Androids camera. I don't know about iPhone, as I don't have access to one.

Comment: @taco: [HTML Media Capture](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/) is alive and well.

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

See [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

> Support:
>
> - Android 3.0 browser - one of the first implementations. Check out this video to see it in action.
> - Chrome for Android (0.16)
> - Firefox Mobile 10.0
> - iOS6 Safari and Chrome (partial support)

Answer (score 5):

We've had some success with this basic approach cobbled together from across the Web:

```
<form method="post" action="takephoto.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in the PHP file we generate unique file names using now() or something similar for storage.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as [the one provided by Jez D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431475/html5-camera-access/12673480#12673480), using the [HTML Media Capture API](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/).

Comment: Not sure why that requires a downvote.  I just answered the question.  Didn't research to make sure I was the only one who'd ever used that approach.  But thanks for keeping me on the straight and narrow.

Comment: No worries, it's just best practice to upvote or improve an existing answer, unless yours is significantly different.

Comment: So...then mark the question as duplicate, not the answer.  I didn't get my answer from Jez D.  Also the inclusion of the enctype and suggestion for generating unique file names is not part of his answer.  I don't much care about being downvoted, but for a duplicate answer?  From three years ago?  That I've never heard of.

Comment: Dave, your answer and Jez's are on this same question. I know your answer wasn't stolen, but see on meta about duplicate answers: [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258558/how-to-deal-with-a-stolen-answer/258835#258835) or [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258344/adding-answers-after-a-correct-answer-already-exists/258370#258370). Your answer was posted almost a year after an existing answer that gives the same solution. As to "three years ago", I've just noticed now the quasi-duplicate answers because now is when I looked at the question. Its age is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I think Opera is the only mobile browser that supports this HTML5 extension.

See note from the author to this thread;

http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/stream-a-webcam-using-javascript-nodejs-android-opera-mobile-web-sockets-and-html5/

Comment: Thanks all. It seems that Opera 12 does not support using Camera. Is there any way to access camera by using HTML5?

Answer (score 3):

I've just recently started working with a tool called Bridgeit.

This is a combination of javascript in the browser and an app on the phone. It seems to work pretty well so far.

http://bridgeit.mobi/

Comment: `bridgeit.camera('id', 'callback', {postURL:'url'})` invokes the camera function of the BridgeIt App with an image data-url thumbnail returned in event.preview passed to callback and the photo uploaded to the specified url.

Comment: @OrangeKing89 the link is down and shows some random ads.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 added support for camera access, you can use it like this:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="user">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">`

Where `user` is for front camera and `environment` is for back camera.

Answer (score 1):

Opera Desktop, Opera mobile and Chrome (after changing some configuration) supports HTML5 camera / microphone access so far.

Comment: Which settings do i need to set in Chrome mobile?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Chrome for Android by enabling the "Enable WebRTC" flag under chrome://flags

I tested on my android phone to access camera on html5 page and it's working.

Comment: If you're giving negative score to 5 years old answer, you should explain what's wrong about the answer. Obviously the answer was given at back then and working.