# How can I read QR code in my phone camera?

Tags: c#, barcode

1. I want to create a website that will be access by handheld devices.
2. I also want my website to have the ability to a scan barcode(QR Code) and display it on a textbox.

My website is create on C#.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it's possible. Google for Java Applet or take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431475/html5-camera-access

Comment: Thanks @Quannt! any suggestion on how can I do it? sample libraries maybe?

Comment: Java applets are not widely supported on handheld devices, though.

Comment: When it comes to accessing phone camera from browser, you don't have many choices. It's not gonna be easy, it's a painful road actually. You have 3 choices as far as I'm aware of: java applet, Windows ActiveX and HTML5 getUserMedia. 
@Thilo : yup, I'm fully aware of that. If I were OP, it would set my focus on a PhoneGap application.

Comment: Hi @Quannt can you please explain this. I did not get it. "If I were OP, it would set my focus on a PhoneGap application."

Comment: If you are targeting handheld devices and your goal is to let the app accesses the devices' hardware parts, PhoneGap is perfect for you, have a read here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview.

Comment: Ok Great! Thanks you so much for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# [QrCode.Net library](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/). This library can even be used on Windows Phone. In iOS applications, QR code scanning is built-in from version 7 and upwards: http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/. On Android there is the [zxing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).