# Check if phone supports camera upload through <input type="file" />

Tags: javascript

In a non-native web-app, is it possible through javascript to (without looking at user agent) check if a phone/browser supports taking a photo with the camera and uploading it through the use of a  element?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431475/html5-camera-access

Comment: That one's about streaming/webcam, I'm looking for photo upload from camera library.