# Uploading Mobile-Captured Picture to Server

Tags: php, mysql, mobile, upload, camera

I've been looking into allowing users to upload pictures taken from their mobile phones, specifically in iOS. I'm currently using the following bit to prompt users:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">
```

However, being inexperienced as I am, I have little knowledge regarding the storage and subsequent uploading-to-the-server of the picture captured. To the best of my understanding,the best course of action would be to upload to a mySQL server using PHP, but I don't know how to do that in PHP or access the PHP document to execute the code. I've tried to phrase this the best I know how with the limited scope of my knowledge, so please excuse any glaring mistakes and the like.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241707/using-form-input-to-access-camera-and-immediately-upload-photos-using-web-app

Comment: Wow that looks very promising. I'm not sure how I didn't see it when researching. Thank you!