# Convert image into base64string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on VS2015 cordova app .I want to send an base 64 string of an image to another server . I have a problem when i get image from gallery and corverting it into base64string . I got the base64string successfully but when i dispalayed it I always get black image . here is my code :

```
   function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
     var largeImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
    basestrg = encodeImageUri(imageURI);

}

function getPhoto(source) {
           navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI, mediaType: Camera.MediaType.Photo,
        sourceType: source
    });
}
function encodeImageUri(imageUri) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        c.width = this.width;
        c.height = this.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = imageUri;
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    return dataURL;
}
```

Please advice .

Comment: Check if the base64 string starts with an identifier if not make sure to add it.

Comment: you draw the image at `onload` with a async callback. So when you build up `dataUrl` few lines below the image has not been drawn yet

Comment: @seahorsepip what is an identifier ?

Comment: @Paolo please explain what should i do

Comment: Is the original image `type` `jpeg` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is beside the context but may help you.
You can upload the image directly from your html5 form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">    
    <input name="userImage" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Get the image data in upload.php file and save as image.    In PHP use `$_FILES` array and for C# use `HttpContext` to save the image.
Ref: [Using form input to access camera and immediately upload photos using web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241707/using-form-input-to-access-camera-and-immediately-upload-photos-using-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't loaded by the time you try to get the data url.

```
function encodeImageUri(imageUri, callback) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        c.width = this.width;
        c.height = this.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        callback(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = imageUri;
}
```

Then change the other function to pass a callback

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
    encodeImageUri(imageURI, function(datauri){
      basestrg = datauri;
      //Now send the string to the server here.
    });

}
```

Comment: ok it solved black box image , but i get large base64string from my image which can't be passed to my web service any idea to reduce this base64strg ?

Comment: @prime not unless you compress the image. The base64 string is literally the binary representation of the image as text. Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size. So if you have a 1MB file you get 1.37MBs of text. I'm not sure why you just dont upload the image directly?

Comment: I want to upload the image directly but I haven't did this before . any idea how can i begin?