# Is mobile camera allowed with accept="image/*"?

Tags: html, file, input, upload

To ensure that my website visitator can pick from the file input dialog box just image files, I would use 
`<input type="file" accept="image/*">`
But a doubt has arisen:
in this way, when **on mobile**, can the user **take a picture** (and then upload it) from the dialog box?
You can see what I'm referring to below. With `accept="image/*"`, can the user pick the camera?
[image: Android]
[image: IOS]

Comment: yes it's possible, can you tell me whats the framework. or is it just vanilla js and HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm just using HTML and jQuery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242035/4423647 duplicated question. have a look at this.

Comment: That is not my question: I want to keep being possible to upload the files from the device without taking a picture