# getUserMedia() not supported in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webcam

I am trying to access my webcam using the getUserMedia() using my own website that run using my own ip address.

it was working fine until i tried my website again. i had tried the other demo site and the error given was getUserMedia is not supported.

Chrome version v47.0.2526.80m 32bits

[image]

I am able to access the webcam if i enter localhost instead of my ipadress. it also work in firefox.

Comment: it work previously without using SSL..

Comment: Yes, it did. On Monday I had to change my site to be all SSL for it work.

Comment: how do i add SSL? i google and most certificate require purchase..

Comment: Startssl has free certs.. on my phone but you can find tutorials on Google for startssl

Comment: i read/watch a few tuts on setting up SSL using starssl but it need a valid domain? this is a sch project and i am testing the website in a intranet environment.

Comment: Does it have to be chrome? Or can you just use Firefox?

Comment: certain features i code only work in chrome..

Comment: Can you downgrade to an earlier version of chrome? Pre 47

Comment: problem solve i am able to create a local SSL file to test my site using this http://www.mytechblog.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Commands-Procedure.txt

Comment: You can provide your IP address as an exception in Chrome. Follow these steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090783/293280

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Chrome is requiring secure origins (HTTPS) for getUserMedia.

> Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc?hl=en

Comment: Is this strictly on mobile?

Answer (score 18):

I am not sure if this exactly solves your problem. However, it might be helpful to someone who is struggling to have getUserMedia() in a working state.

I came across a medium link that helped me solve this issue.

Go to : chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

Enable the option.

Also, there will be a checkbox provided below. Use that to provide the link to your HTTP server.

[Referr to this image for better clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIOqU.png)

Provide the port number too. (In my case it is 8000)

Source: https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/enabling-the-microphone-camera-in-chrome-for-local-unsecure-origins-9c90c3149339

Comment: Perfect answer, worked for me. one thing is we should add the http host origin in the same otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 13):

Chrome *finally* implemented the new [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) method, but they added a security that will prevent the calls from unsecure address (non https or non localhost servers)

You will call it like this :

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(function(mediaStream){
    window.stream = mediaStream;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
    video.play();
});
```

Or you can use the official webRTC polyfill [adpater.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/adapter.js) library.

```
var constraints = { video: true, audio: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```