# JavaScript GetUserMedia using Chrome with localhost without HTTPS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, localhost, getusermedia

I didn't know how to express it in the title, but I'm having an issue with Chrome.

I'm trying to use `GetUserMedia()` and `GetPosition()` in Chrome. I know that it requires SSL certification first, unless you're on `localhost`. The thing is, I can't try my project on my computer, so I must use my smart phone, and in order to access `localhost` through my smartphone, I must use the machine's IP address (192.168.1.4). The problem is that Chrome doesn't consider this IP address as `localhost`, so it requires an SSL certificate.

Is there any way I can test my project on my smartphone without having to install an SSL certififcate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a service like https://ngrok.com/ to map a public DNS address with SSL certificate to a port on your local machine.

Answer (score 29):

#### Add your IP address to Chrome's `Insecure origins treated as secure setting`.

1. Go to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` in Chrome.
2. Find the `Insecure origins treated as secure setting`.
3. Enable it.
4. Enter in `http://cntral.me:3000`.
5. Relaunch Chrome.
6. Voila!

[image]

See https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/enabling-the-microphone-camera-in-chrome-for-local-unsecure-origins-9c90c3149339 for a good walkthrough as well.

Comment: Flag not available on Chrome 78 for iOS unfortunately. Curious about Android. (OP mentions smart phone).

Comment: @rnbrady Ah, good call. I didn't check and I didn't see the smart phone mentioned in the question. Too bad they don't have something similar on mobile. This saved us a tonne of headache with local/dev SSL certs.

Comment: you the beauty thumbs up,

Comment: This solutions fit perfect with my problem, I have a CRA app and needed to open de camera from mobiles with a secure connection with localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to host a Web service on a computer and access it from a smart phone using the hostname `localhost`.

Two options come to mind:

First, if your smart phone is rooted, you can change `/etc/hosts` so that the name `localhost` resolves to `192.168.1.4` instead of to `127.0.0.1`.

Second, if you can run an SSH server on your computer, you can set up an SSH client on your phone to forward traffic on some port to another port on a different machine.

For example, in ConnectBot for Android, you can

1. create a profile for your computer running an SSH server on `192.168.1.4`
2. long-press the profile, and select "Edit port forwards" and then "Add port forward" from the port forwarding menu
3. configure it to "Local" and then choose a local source port that can be claimed by a non-root user on your phone (say, `8080`) and on the bottom line, use `localhost:80` (or whatever port the computer is running the service on) to make the SSH server have the forwarding tunnel direct to itself on port 80

This will cause all traffic directed at `localhost:8080` on your phone to go to `192.168.1.4:80` on your computer. The browser has no idea that the `localhsot:8080` service is actually just an SSH tunnel to `192.168.1.4:80`, so it will treat it like any other `localhost` address.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without an SSL certificate at all by tunneling the webserver to your phone's localhost.

I use [termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) to run this command (on the phone itself):

> ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 192.168.0.172

(Leave the ssh session open)

Then go to http://localhost:8080/ on your phone.

If you don't want the session to time out, you can use autossh:

> autossh -M 0 -L 8080:localhost:8080 192.168.0.172

Important note: Your development machine (or dev server) needs to be accessible through ssh. For Linux, this can be done by installing open-ssh and enabling/starting the sshd service. You can look up guides for this online.

Comment: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.... port 22: Connection refused`
What can be wrong? Port is not correct. In my case should be `4200`

Comment: @gkucmierz Port 22 is the port used for ssh. You need to configure your server so that it accepts ssh sessions. Here is a guide on how to do this for ubuntu https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/