# Developing webapp on mobile - https security problems

Tags: http, security, localhost, host, getusermedia

I am developing web-app on mobile which is using user camera & microphone.

When I want to run it on mobile in same network. I am running server on `--host 0.0.0.0` to be able to run it on mobile.

The problem is that my dev server is running on `http` protocol, and mobile browser is not allowing `getUserMedia` in that case.

What is good solution to solve it?

I know I can set flags on my mobile browser to allow insecure connection, but it is also my private phone, so I don't want to go this path.

Comment: why not switch to https protocol ?

Comment: I will try. I am using angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getUserMedia() in chrome 47 without using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)

Comment: Nope, I am trying this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144036/javascript-getusermedia-using-chrome-with-localhost-without-https
I don't want to use flags in my private device

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> dev server is running on `http` protocol, and mobile browser is not allowing getUserMedia in that case.

You Can't Do That™. You *must* use `https` to serve your web pages and Javascript for this kind of application, or all browsers deny access to getUserMedia() and other similar browser-resident APIs.

True for desktop and mobile browsers.

Because cybercreeps.