# Navigator.getUserMedia and Navigator.webkitGetUserMedia undefined after updating to Chrome 74

Tags: google-chrome, webkit

After updating from Chrome 73 to 74 `navigator.getUserMedia` and `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` return undefined.

Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia I see that getUserMedia is actually deprecated in favor of `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`, but in my case navigator.mediaDevices too is undefined so I cannot use it.

Anyone knows if it's a bug in the latest release of Chrome or if I need to use something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since version 74 of Chrome `navigator.getUserMedia`, `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` and `navigator.mediaDevices` can be used only in secure context (https), otherwise they are undefined.

I've understood what the problem was while writing the question, as usual...

Comment: thnx Mauro, I had the same problem and I couldn't figure out it.

Comment: You are welcome Aida, actually I was surprised to don't find an answer on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: :) another thing that it has became me wonder is : it works sometimes, and although my website is not in secure context(https), somethimes 'navigator.getUserMedia' is not undefined :|

Comment: In my case it's easier: in https it always works, in https I always have the problem. Mysteries.

Comment: Is there any way we can make it works while using HTTP? I am testing my web apps, hence the http mode ....

Answer (score 5):

I tried a small setting on chrome and it turned out to work for me.

I enabled: chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

and provided my HTTP server link along with the port.

It worked for me.

You could refer to the following: 
1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472984/12906501
2. https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/enabling-the-microphone-camera-in-chrome-for-local-unsecure-origins-9c90c3149339

Hope it helps!! Thanks.

Comment: Sounds hazardous.

Comment: I'm not sure what the state was when this asnwer/comment were added, but Chrome at least now requires you to whitelist specific sites and doesn't even appear to allow wildcarding in the URLs. For development on your own site that's being served over HTTP locally, this seems fine. If this blindly allowed all sites to access the camera/mic even over HTTP, yes, that would be hazardous.

Answer (score 1):

In my case **HTTP** was the cause of undefined for `navigator.mediaDevices`

with **HTTPS** works as expected