# Heroku Hosted Page throws error - navigator.mediaDevices is undefined

Tags: firefox, webrtc, peerjs

The following piece of code works fine when served from localhost, but when deployed to Heroku fails stating : 
TypeError: navigator.mediaDevices is undefined

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}).then(function(stream){
    video = $('#myVid')[0];
    video.srcObject = stream;

    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
    };
```

Including adapter.js from WebRtC does not help. Have you had a similar experience and got it resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Like Google did years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215937/getusermedia-not-supported-in-chrome/34216434#34216434), Firefox is now [(since v69)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1335740) requiring a secure-context to access the MediaDevices API.
You must serve your website from https.

Answer (score 0):

*To extend Kaiido's answer.*

In the case of running applications locally,

- `localhost` is considered secure ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts))
- `0.0.0.0` is not considered secure. The application can be visited by other clients on the same network.

For example, if you launch a NextJS server, the output might suggest you could visit `0.0.0.0:3000`:

```
started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

You should visit the `http://localhost:3000` to avoid this error.