# Run Daphne in production on (or forwarded to?) port 443

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, daphne

I am trying to build a speech recognition-based application. It runs on Django with Django-channels and Daphne, and Nginx as the web server, on an Ubuntu EC2 instance on AWS. It should run in the browser, so I am using WebRTC to get the audio stream – or at least that’s the goal. I'll call my domain `mysite.co` here.

Django serves the page properly on `http://www.mysite.co:8000` and Daphne seems to run too, the logs show

```
2022-10-17 13:05:02,950 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2022-10-17 13:05:02,951 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2022-10-17 13:05:02,951 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2022-10-17 13:05:02,965 INFO     Listening on TCP address [Private IPv4 address of my EC2 instance]:8000
2022-10-17 13:05:02,965 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
```

I used the [Daphne docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html) to set up Daphne with supervisor. There, they use port 8000.

My first Nginx config file `nginx.conf` (I shouldn't use that one, should I?) looks like this:

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        # Gzip Settings
        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        upstream channels-backend {
        server mysite.co:80;
        }

        server {
            location / {
                try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
            }
            location @proxy_to_app {
                proxy_pass http://mysite.co;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }}

}

# and the mail settings, but I don't use them
```

Currently, the homepage of my server just serves a HTML that I set in my first Nginx server block (I set this up while figuring out how to get TLS on Nginx, I don't need the HTML here):

```
server {

        root /var/www/mysite/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mysite.co www.mysite.co;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mysite.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mysite.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mysite.co www.mysite.co;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

I need WebRTC to access the audio stream that should run through Daphne, but for that, [I need HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215937/getusermedia-not-supported-in-chrome/34216154#34216154) because you can’t access user media via unencrypted protocols. I have created a TLS cert with Let’s Encrypt for Nginx (cf. above), but of course this only works on port 443. I can’t (and probably shouldn’t be able to?) reach port 8000 via HTTPS.

I am a bit lost at this point, my Nginx experience is very limited. Do I need to bind port 8000 to 443? If so, what do I need to do with my Nginx config for the HTML file that is currently served there? Am I on the right track at all?

If I should share other config files from Nginx or supervisor, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the wrong track, actually it's very straightforward. There's no need to run it on port 8000, you can run it conveniently on 443.

You don't configure the SSL in the Nginx server blocks, but you do it right in the place where you start the Daphne server adding `-e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem` to your `daphne` command. You must have generated an SSL certificate previously of course, Let'sEncrypt works just fine here as well. `privateKey` is `privkey.pem` and `certKey` is `fullchain.pem` then.

(This snippet in itself won't work, depending on your needs you might have to add other flags as well like `-u` or `--endpoint`.)