# Ionic-Upload picture from camera or gallery in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I'm developing an Ionic App for Android and I want to let the user upload a picture from camera or gallery, as the standard browser does.
The Ionic app uses the web, but when I want to upload a picture it only let me upload a picture from files.

So this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: You should probably show how you produced the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your config.xml (I am using ionic and crosswalk)

```
<access origin="image/*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

This worked for me, and is based on this question:

[How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app)