# Management web-app and mobile version

Tags: android, ios, cakephp

I am building a management web application based on php + mysql, developed with CakePhp framework.

Now I have been commissioned to develop the mobile version, mainly for android and ios devices (no windows, until now...)
leaving apart that right now i have to study from scratch mobile apps development, the questions are:

1. I figured out that mobile version of the app cannot be written in php...i know that android is based upon java, but what about ios?
2. it seems that I have to develop the mobile twice (waiting for windows os request...), so the second question is if there is a tool that could help to write once and to port everywhere (it seems the original java definition...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake, even early version of it, takes to themes very gracefully.  Just add to your existing website a mobile-friendly template, customized a bit for your brand look, and you won't need to learn a thing about mobile apps.

Comment: well, thanx, the solution you suggest might be VERY useful and easy. but what about the possible use of mobile hardware and / or sensors, suche as camera, gps and so on?

Comment: that wasn't your question :-)

Comment: Actually thank you bitdiego, I learned something too..  Here is SO about interfacing with a mobile's camera: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app  You'd only need to check you're -on- a mobile before doing something along those lines.

Comment: PS:  In PHP I use http://mobiledetect.net/ to try and figure out what kind of device I'm running on.  Not foolproof by any means, but a decent crack at orientation..

Comment: woah! you are great man! this is really what I was looking for:
really thanx a lot!

Comment: Good that worked for you :-).  Here's a more general/recent reference too: https://www.clickz.com/web-apps-bringing-the-advantages-of-native-apps-to-a-web-browser/90689/