# How to read barcode from camera using coldfusion?

Tags: html, coldfusion, barcode

I need to create a bootstrap web page that will allow the user to read a barcode from the camera.

I am using Coldfusion but I can't seem to find any resource to help read the barcode from the camera.

Ideally the user clicks a button to open the camera and read the barcode then submit it to an API.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CF for a web app, then you will have to add code to your web page to get permission to use the camera. Here is some information on that:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/
or this:
[How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app)
Then you store the image in a form Input and submit it back to CF. Use the CfUpload to put the picture into a local file. After the image is received, use a library like Zxing to decode the image https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Does that help?