# html5 input file auto save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, camera

## Background

I made a web app based on React.
I allowed users to upload their picture by `<input type="file">`.
And if they click a button, browser shows some options

- Take picture or video
- Gallery
- Explore...

And users click the [take picture or video] button then, default camera app is opened. This is normal process as you know.

## Problem

If they take picture in a browser, it isn't saved into their gallery. I think browser disallow it for security.

But, I want to make their smartphone **save the picture into their gallery** that they take right before automatically.

Is this possible?
Or should I make a native-app to make this?

Comment: This article (uploading a file with AJAX) might point you in the right direction https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata

Comment: I did upload file with AJAX, What I want is to save photo that taken in browser by `<input type="file">` into the smartphone's gallery automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a mobile's camera from a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app)